# embulkでs3のデータをrdsへETLしようとするとFOREIGN_KEY制約のエラーが発生する

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-s3, embulk

embulkでs3のデータをrdsへETLしようとするとFOREIGN_KEY制約のエラーが発生します。
具体的には以下のようなエラーです。

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`outputdb`.`TABLE_HISTORY`, CONSTRAINT `fk_TABLE_HISTORY_TABLE_HISTORY1` FOREIGN KEY (`PRIMARY_ID`, `SECOND_PRIMARY_ID`) REFERENCES `TABLE)
```

上のようにPrimary keyが二つのカラムに設定してあります（複合主キー）。

### 試したこと

mysql側でset FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;を設定

embulk のoutに以下のように設定を記述。
before_load: 'set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'

Answer (score 0):

これで解決：

フォーリンキーエラー参照し以下のコマンドでフォーリンキーを確認

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE テーブル名;
```

フォーリンキーを削除。

```
ALTER TABLE テーブル名 DROP FOREIGN KEY 外部キー名;
```